Xcode 15.2 is missing iOS 17.2 device support
Suddenly Xcode 15.2 stopped compiling stuff.
It notifies, that iOS 17.2 device support is missing, while it was working a day before, and no updates, nor system changes were applied.
Exactly the same thing happened on 3 different machines, so it only proves, the issue came from apple.
If selecting to download device support, it downloads, but after that nothing changes.
What could be the optimal solution?

So I have found 2 working solutions, tried on different machines:

is to update to a newer macos, if nothing is applicable, then updating to latest beta;
Installing the Xcode 15.3 from app store, then reinstalling manually the xcode 15.2 "on the side";

Note: all machines were using solely xcode 15.2 which was manually installed (that is requirement for specific deploy), so the problem might occur because of such specific setup;
